# Merging req.params and req.url in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

First of all, I have the following route:

`route: '/list/:param1'`

Im sending the following request to the server:

`url: '/list/someParam?param2=foo&param3=bar`

After that, express is giving to me two important objects that i need, the `req.url` and the `req.params`.

I want to get an object that merges both url and params. Im using the following code:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    var url = require('url');
    var queryObject = url.parse(req.url, true).query;

    console.log(queryObject);
    console.log(req.params);
    console.log(req.params.length);
}
```

So it logs something like:

```
{ param2: 'foo', param3: 'bar' }
[ param1: 'someParam' ]
0
```

Now, assuming that I dont know the name of the params, I need to have an object with the information from both `req.url` and `req.params`. Here are my questions:

1) How can I do to get something like:

```
{ param1: 'someParam', param2: 'foo', param3: 'bar' }
```

2) Why is `req.params` logging something like an array? And if it is an array, why is it returning me `0` as its length?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `req.params` is not an array. It's an object, but behaves like an array in some cases. [Reference](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params).

Comment: I'm surprised you see anything at all. req.params **should** be empty as it's not populated until the route is processed.

Comment: This cannot be easily done. req.params isn't populated until the route is processed, after all the other middleware is normally run. You *can* do it, but you'll have to wrap every route callback with the middleware. `app.get('/list/:param1', middlware(function(req, res) { /* normal route handler here */ }));`

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query) instead of parsing the URL again.
2. I'm guessing Express has a custom `toString` implementation for that particular object.

You can also look up both in order of importance using [`req.param(name)`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.param)

Comment: `req.query` doesnt include params in `req.params`.

Comment: Right, but you can use it instead of `url.parse`. To look up both you can use `req.param(url)`